Imposing a specific structure for building IRIs in JSON-LD schema
I am fairly new to JSON-LD and currently getting familiar with the concept of IRI. I have a schema, saying a very simple one:
{
  "@context": {
    "ex": "http://example.com/",
    "Person": {
      "@id": "ex:Person",
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "name": "ex:name",
    "age": "ex:age",
    "address": "ex:address"
  }
}

My question is how do impose a specific IRI structure every time I create an instance of Person? Is there a way to do so? Can this be done programmatically in a JSON-LD schema? For example, I would like that my IRIs to look like this:
ex:Person/aSpecificPerson/aVersion

I was looking at examples such as Azure Digital Twins, but I am struggling to come up with an approach that, no matter what the resource is, would programmatically create IRIs of a specific format for instances, properties etc.
Thank you
